# Raspberry Pi Imager on Ubnutu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-22.04

I'm setting up my laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 and cannot install the Raspberry Pi Imager

My simple script

```
echo -e "$LOG_INFO Install Raspi Imager"
curl -L https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/imager/imager_latest_amd64.deb --output raspi-imager.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ./raspi-imager.deb
rm raspi-imager.deb
```

results in

```
[INFO] Install Raspi Imager
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   246  100   246    0     0   1378      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1382
100  356k  100  356k    0     0  1106k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1106k
[sudo] password for sebastian: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'rpi-imager' instead of './raspi-imager.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rpi-imager : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The dependency "libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0)" is not installable. Anyone got an idea on how I can fix that? Could this be related to Ubuntu 22-04?

Comment: Don't grab packages manually you mess up dependencies. Run `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install rpi-imager`

Comment: That was it ... many thanks